# Error : statement requires more resources than resource queue allows

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I tried to create a table from the below mentioned table, and there are multiple left joins. When I tried to run one by one till 3rd left-join it is running fine, but from 4th left-join (*araos_ent_plan_ta_apid* ) if I run I'm receiving the following error. Tried multiple ways by creating index in the previous tables on the badge column and applied brackets () between columns in 4th left join however didn't worked. How to resolve this?

```
from araos_ent_gu_apid t1       

left join araos_master_ent_apid cust on t1.gu_id = cust.gbl_ult_idntfr
left join alteryx_core_account A on A.UCID =  cust.UCID 

left join alteryx_core_user B on A.core_quota_rep = B.user_id  --house account from the sfdc 
left join araos_ent_plan_ta_apid ta on cust.ucid = ta.ucid 
                   and ((ta.badge_number_updated1 = b.Badge_number) OR (ta.badge_number_updated2 = b.Badge_number)) --retrieve district id & area
left join w_sales_hierarchy_d sh on sh.dstrct_id = ta.dstrct_id   
left join araos_ent_plan_hist_apid ZASAP on A.account_id = ZASAP.Account__c
```

Comment: MySQL <> postgres; and you'll need improve the formatting on your query. The FROM in the middle of all that makes no sense.

Comment: I posted only the part of query which was causing error.

Comment: You can't put a FROM in the middle of JOINs; and it's usually best to at least post the whole query. Including the CREATE statements for the tables involved, and samples of source data and desired results are also good to have.  Also, the Code Sample `{}` formatting button can help to make your query not just a long run on of syntax.

Comment: A query that can't be run can't cause an error, other than the syntax error telling it can't be run. How do you know what part of an unrunnable query caused a run time error?

Comment: Please don't tag your question with random tags.  Are you using mysql, or postgresql?  If postgresql, are you using the version you indicate here, the one from when you asked the same question yesterday?